# Custom translation file (Not using Locales/Multisite)

Tags: craft3, language

Is it possible to make Craft 3 load a custom translation/language file? Even if not using multisite or locales?

My use case for this is just to change the way certain things are said. E.g. `'Invalid username or password.' => 'Invalid username or password.'`, when a user logs in. I wanted to be a bit more descriptive on this.

I can see the translation files in `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/translations/[language code here]` so I assume theres a way of adding bespoke ones to this, but outside of the `vendor` folder.

I just can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Static Translations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/static-translations.html).

You can add a translation file for English to English (or whatever language you are using) to override default translations. In your case, you'll want to override the `app` translation category:

In your project folder:

```
website.com/
└── translations/
    └── en/
        └── app.php
```

And in `app.php`:

```
<?php

return [
    'Invalid username or password.' => 'Something new'
];
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix it by doing this. My issue was I was calling the file `site.php` not `app.php`. Doh.